# Why Android Activity Close Silently

Tags: android

I have in issue with my application that running on a POS with Android 4.2.2

My app has a ListView, with at max 6 static items, uses android_serial_port to print and starts on system boot.

My App should be always active, but, after few hours of work without receive user input, it closes silently without crash messages.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem?

This is some code:

```
private static  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> serviceList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Remove Title
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //Remove notification bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Remove navigation bar
        mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(8);

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Tag");
        mWakeLock.acquire();

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter=new ListAdapter(this, serviceList, numberButtons);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // ...
    }
}
```

This is the logcat:

```
[ 01-12 17:01:12.662   500:  518 E/ActivityManager ]

ANR in net.my_app

PID: 9432

Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x50000014 (has extras) }

Load: 2.03 / 2.28 / 2.32

CPU usage from 5161ms to 33ms ago:

8.7% 595/com.android.systemui: 7.7% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 127 minor

2.5% 500/system_server: 0.9% user + 1.5% kernel / faults: 42 minor 6 major

1.5% 13132/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 1.5% kernel

1.1% 170/surfaceflinger: 0.5% user + 0.5% kernel

0.3% 14/cfinteractive: 0% user + 0.3% kernel

0% 75/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 0% kernel

0% 725/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel

0.1% 12669/kworker/u:0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel

13% TOTAL: 9.1% user + 3.7% kernel + 0.9% iowait

CPU usage from 1938ms to 2453ms later:

7.4% 500/system_server: 0% user + 7.4% kernel / faults: 1 minor

7.4% 518/ActivityManager: 1.8% user + 5.5% kernel

1.8% 522/android.ui: 1.8% user + 0% kernel

1.3% 595/com.android.systemui: 1.3% user + 0% kernel

1.3% 595/ndroid.systemui: 1.3% user + 0% kernel

1.5% 13132/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 1.5% kernel

5.7% TOTAL: 1.9% user + 3.8% kernel
```

and

```
[ 01-12 17:03:32.588  9432: 9442 E/AndroidRuntime ]

FATAL EXCEPTION: FinalizerWatchdogDaemon

Process: net.my_app, PID: 9432

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

at com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher.finalize(BinderInternal.java:47)

at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:187)

at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Are you using `Service` that starts upon `BOOT_COMPLETED`?

Comment: I'm using an BroadcastReceiver with an intent filter for `BOOT_COMPLETED`

Comment: And then, are you using a `Service`? Is it a `Service` that "after few hours of work without receiver user input, closes silently without crash message"? What is crashing? Explain better and show some code.

Comment: I have edited my question to inserting some code. 
I do not know if my Activity crash, I only know that after a few hours closes

Comment: `public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, DialogEditServizio.NoticeDialogFragment{ .. }`

Comment: having a log of the closing moment would definitely help

Comment: I started the logcat and I'm waiting for crash, but unfortunately it takes time.

As soon as I will be posting the log

Comment: Is the app visible when it "crashes"?  That is, is your app's Activity the one visible on the phone screen, when the app is stopped?

Comment: Yes, it's the one visible.

Comment: @shkschneider I edit my question with logcat.

Comment: Have you found solution or root cause for the problem? If yes, would you mind to update this question with solution?

Comment: @YuriyChernyshov I never found a solution for this problem. The only thing that I have done is add a app autorestart code triggered on unattended exit.